# How Can i Get to transform a Maybe to a Value?

Tags: purescript

I having a problem with my code I'm trying to compile it but it throws me Could Not Match **Maybe Element** with **Element**

Why? how does Maybe Work?, how do I convert it to a Value? why is so hard to understand monads and functors,
and why isn't an easy library to get some newbie getting started wit purescript?
:P

(for those who didn't understand I was just asking the first 3)

```
module Main where

import Prelude --(Unit, bind, pure,  ($), (<$>))
import Effect (Effect)
import Data.Maybe --(Just,Maybe,fromJust, fromMaybe)
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)
import Effect.Console (log)

import Web.HTML (window)
import Web.HTML.Window (document)
import Web.HTML.HTMLDocument (toNonElementParentNode)
import Web.Event.Event (Event, target)
import Web.HTML.HTMLInputElement (value, fromEventTarget)

import Web.DOM.NonElementParentNode (NonElementParentNode,getElementById)
import Web.DOM.Node (setTextContent)
import Web.DOM.Element (Element,toNode)
import Web.Event.EventTarget (addEventListener)

pname = "#inputName" :: String
bname = "#badgeName" :: String

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  nod1 <- returnNonElementParentNode
--querySelector :: QuerySelector -> ParentNode -> Effect (Maybe Element)
  elementTarget <- getElementById pname nod1
--addEventListener :: EventType -> EventListener -> Boolean -> EventTarget
  addEventListener "input" updateBadge false elementTarget

updateBadge :: Event -> Unit
updateBadge event = do
  nod2 <- returnNonElementParentNode
  elementTarget <- getElementById bname nod2

  tget <- target event
  inml <- fromEventTarget tget
  input <- value inml

  badge <- toNode (pure elementTarget)

  if not(badge == Nothing) 
    then setTextContent input (toNode badge) 
    else Nothing

returnNonElementParentNode :: Effect NonElementParentNode
returnNonElementParentNode = do 
  win <- window
  doc <- document win
  --let nd  = toNonElementParentNode doc
  let 
      nod = toNonElementParentNode doc
  pure nod
```

I just want to understand how to get the input value from an htmlInputElement and pass it to the textContent of Another HTMLElement

pretty much how to convert a **Maybe** to a **Value** to pass to **toNode** function

Comment: Doesn't purescript have pattern matching? If it has the same as Haskell, you could just replace that `if` with a `case` and then within the `Just` side you would have the bare value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- pattern matching ... https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Pattern-Matching.md
- Data.Maybe#v:maybe ... https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maybe/4.0.1/docs/Data.Maybe#v:maybe
- Data.Maybe#v:fromMaybe ... https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maybe/4.0.1/docs/Data.Maybe#v:fromMaybe
- Partial.Unsafe#v:unsafePartial + Data.Maybe#v:fromJust  https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-partial/2.0.1/docs/Partial.Unsafe#v:unsafePartial https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maybe/4.0.1/docs/Data.Maybe#v:fromJust